# Django admin/model/add/ выдает ошибку "Page not found" на с Cpanel

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Поднял проект Django на Cpanel. Теперь когда пытаюсь добавить запись в админке при нажатии на кнопку сохранить выдает ошибку Page not found. Хотя локально никакой ошибки нету. Самое интересное, что при обращении на admin//add  get запросом все работает и форма для добавления записи открывается, но когда нажимаешь на кнопку сохранить которая ведет на эту же страницу только с методом post уже выходит ошибка page not found. Надеюсь на вашу помощь!
Вот мой файл urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')),
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'news/', views.news, name='news'),
]
```

Comment: Нет ли в сохраняемой Вами модели def save( .. ?

Comment: Заметил, что эта ошибка происходит у моделей с полем ImageField. Если этого поля в модели нет, то все сохраняется

Comment: Что за cPanel? дебаг режим у вас включен? в логах сервера есть что то? MEDIA_ROOT у вас указан? он доступен для записи?

Comment: @0xdef Дебаг режим в Django включен. В логах сервера ничего нет. MEDIA_ROOT указан и есть доступ на запись. Вот что выдает дебаг: Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://my-addres.ru/admin/main/gallery/add/
Raised by: django.contrib.admin.options.add_view URLconf defined in vikri.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^admin/
^ckeditor/
^$ [name='index']
^news/$ [name='news']
^__debug__/
^media/(?P<path>.*)$
The current path, main/gallery/add/, didn't match any of these.

Comment: а CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = '' указали? и если пробуете через дев сервер нужны урл для статики + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)

Comment: @0xdef В CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH указал путь относительно MEDIA_ROOT, но ошибка было и до ckeditor'a и в urls.py я написал так :  urlpatterns += [
    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve, {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
].......... В админке у меня стоит валидация на обязательное заполнение полей и если нажать на "сохранить" не заполнив ни одного поля, то все равно выходит эта ошибка "page not found". Что за напасть не понимаю чтоб ее

Comment: @0xdef Заметил еще одну странность, если перед отправкой формы методом пост в админке(нажатием кнопки сохранить) открыть инструменты разработчика и удалить содержимое атрибут "name" из input type="file", то ошибка не выходит. Если содержимое атрибута "name" поменять на другое, то ошибка все равно выходит